# Unable to boot from a CD-R disk

Tags: windows-installer, cd-burning, cd-r

I want to install puppy Linux in my MSI Megabook S270, as my laptop doesn't support usb flash drive for booting, so, I bought some CD-R disk and burn them with Free ISO burner but when I tried to boot my laptop from it is just booting my HDD os and not booting from the cd drive.
Please help any suggestions.

Comment: When you start from the powered off status, you should be able to press F12 a couple of times and bring up the boot menu. Can you do this? Check your documentation for the correct keystroke

Comment: MSI is usually F11 or DEL

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to change the boot order in the BIOS configuration of that computer.
You can usually access a BIOS with F2 or DEL keys while the computer is turning on (that being said, as **soon** as you press the start button, you should spam either of these keys).

Then, there you can "change the order" of "boot" devices, so you need to "increase" the priority of the DVD/CD reader to be over the internal HDD of the laptop.
If the CD-R is correctly burnt, then it **should** boot into puppy linux.

Comment: no need to do this if it has a boot menu.